# Using js and ajax to retrieve data from django server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to load info on mouse hover, mouse event is working but don't know if it's hitting the url

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
     $('.user').hover(function (e) {
         var offset = $(this).offset();
         var left = e.pageX;
         var top = e.pageY;
         var theHeight = $('#myPopoverContent').height();
         $('#myPopoverContent').show();
         $('#myPopoverContent').css('left', (left+10) + 'px');
         $('#myPopoverContent').css('top', (top-(theHeight/2)-10) + 'px');
          
          $.ajax({
            url: $(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url")/,
            type: 'get',
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
          });
         
     });


     $('#myPopoverContent').focusin(function (e) {
         $('#myPopoverContent').active();
       });

    $('#myPopoverContent').mouseout(function (e) {
         $('#myPopoverContent').hide();
       });           
  });
```

```html
<div class="user-block">
   <span class="username" data-url="{% url 'pop_user'   question.user %}">
   <a class="user" href="{% url 'profile' question.user %}">
     {{question.user.profile.get_screen_name }}
   </a>
   </span>
</div>
```

**I have views function accordingly**
I want to return the data from views, but it;s not working

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Is there any errors? Is it not returning the data?. Post the corresponding views also

Comment: you have an error in `url: $(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url")/,`  change it to `url: $(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url")+"/"`,

Comment: my view is this:

'def pop_user(request, username):
    print('user')
    profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    return render(request, 'profile/pop_user.html', {
        'profile': profile,
     
        })'

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I have posted views above, have a look if I made a mistake

Comment: @Nitesh Your views sends context as profile and you are trying referencing  it with different name. Post the views in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in `url: $(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url")/,` change it to `url: $(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url")+"/",` then the syntax error would be resolved.

Or as mentioned by @ArpitSolanki in the comments, adding the `"/"` isn't required all together. So, you can remove it.

Comment: URL is already reversed so appending slash is not needed, only removing it will work